# How to aggregate data on milliseconds without dropping empty time intervals?

Tags: r, aggregate, dplyr, plyr

I am working with time series stock market data, and have the need to aggregate data on a millisecond basis. I have figured out how to do it but it doesn't work the way I want it to with previoustick() or last().

```
cuts = seq.POSIXt(from = min(A$DateTime), to = max(A$DateTime), by = by)
my_df = data.frame(DateTime=A$DateTime, MQ=A$MQ)
my_df$Time = cut(my_df$DateTime, breaks = cuts)
avgvwap = ddply(my_df, .(Time), summarize, MQ=mean(MQ), .drop = FALSE)

length(cuts)
[1] 227252
nrow(avgvwap)
[1] 227252
```

This does exactly what I want it to just like the `aggregatets()` function except for in the situation when I use `previoustick()` or `last()` as the function as oppose to `mean()` or `sum()`.

The `.drop = FALSE` basically preserves the the time frames in which there is no data available. It simply gives me an NA or NAN in the empty time frame. This handles it perfectly for mean or sum but doesn't preserve it for `last()` or `previoustick()` even though I set '.drop = FALSE'

```
avgvwap = ddply(my_df, .(Time), summarize, MQ=previoustick(MQ), .drop = FALSE)    
nrow(avgvwap)
[1] 98890
```

As you can see, the number of rows reduces because it throws out the empty time frames. It does the same thing if I use `last()` instead of `previoustick()`

How do I get previoustick or last to work without dropping the empty time frames? 
Will this function not be able to handle it at all?

Should I use some other fucntion instead of last or previoustick? Is summarize the problem? Or should I not be using `ddply`?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, ready to copy-paste-run, with packages, dummy data, and your code.

Comment: `dput(A[50,])
structure(list(DateTime = structure(1448855100.421, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "Asia/Kolkata"), BWAP = 80901.875, AWAP = 82814.2857142857, 
    MQ = 81858.0803571429), .Names = c("DateTime", "BWAP", "AWAP", 
"MQ"), row.names = 50L, class = "data.frame")`

Comment: @lukeA The packages I use is `highfrequency`, `xts`, `zoo`and `plyr`

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be able to aggregate like that:

```
time <- Sys.time()
indices <- seq(time, time+1, by = 0.1)
values <- 1:length(indices)
breaks <- cut(as.numeric(indices), c(-Inf, seq(time, time+1, by = 0.2), Inf))
aggregate(values, list(breaks), sum)
#                      Group.1  x
# 1         (-Inf,1458732573.1]  1
# 2 (1458732573.1,1458732573.3]  5
# 3 (1458732573.3,1458732573.5]  9
# 4 (1458732573.5,1458732573.7] 13
# 5 (1458732573.7,1458732573.9] 17
# 6 (1458732573.9,1458732574.1] 21
```